# React Native: Scrollview click outside of Textbox

Tags: react-native

I encountered the following issue: I have a view with two textboxes and one text button. Ones i enter something in the textbox and click on the text button, i have to click twice so that it actually works. If i replace the Scrollview by a View it works. Is there a fix for it?

```
var TestScreen = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
   return (
     <ScrollView>
       <TextInput
      placeholder='test' 
       style = {{
         height: 50, 
          backgroundColor: 'green',
       }} />
      <TextInput
      placeholder='test' 
       style = {{
         height: 50, 
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
       }} />
       <Text onPress={() => alert('click')} style = {{
       backgroundColor: 'orange', 
       }} > Text </Text>
     </ScrollView> 
   );
  }
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290787/touchableopacity-as-item-in-listview-only-reacts-after-textinput-has-lost-focus

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` to the `ScrollView` props?

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>  
   ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank for saving my day :)

Comment: This is a really great answer.

Comment: Thank you Hossein, I had this issue, and this answer solved it.