# React Native: TouchableOpacity onPress problems inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native

I am running react native 0.24.1 and I am experiencing an issue with the `<TouchableOpacity>` component when it is placed inside an `<ScrollView>`.

Its **onPress** events fire fine but there is a special case when they do not.
If along with the `<TouchableOpacity>` component you have a `<TextInput>`, and the current focus is on the `<TextInput>` box, then you may click on the `<TouchableOpacity>` and you will see its **onPress** event WILL NOT be fired.

At least the first time you do it. Once the focus is NOT on the `<TextInput>` anymore, you can now press on the `<TouchableOpacity>` component and its **onPress** event will fire just fine.

Note that if the `<TouchableOpacity>` component is placed inside a `<View>` instead of an `<ScrollView>` everything works as expected and the above issue does not apply.

Here is some code to demonstrate the problem:

```
const React = require('react-native');
const {
  Component,
  Dimensions,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TouchableOpacityTest extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {count_onPress:0,count_onPressIn:0,count_onPressOut:0,count_onLongPress:0};
  }
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  onPressEvent(what,e) {
    console.log('what:',what);
    let newState = {};
    newState['count_'+what] = ++this.state['count_'+what];
    this.setState(newState);
  }
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  render() {
    let touchableProps = {
      onPress: this.onPressEvent.bind(this,'onPress'),
      onPressIn: this.onPressEvent.bind(this,'onPressIn'),
      onPressOut: this.onPressEvent.bind(this,'onPressOut'),
      onLongPress: this.onPressEvent.bind(this,'onLongPress'),
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'flex-start',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'blue'}} >
        <ScrollView style={{width:Dimensions.get('window').width*0.9,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <TextInput style={{backgroundColor:'rgb(200,200,200)',marginTop:14}}
            placeholder="Focus on me,hide keyboard,and click on text below"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity {...touchableProps} >
            <Text style={{fontSize:20,backgroundColor:'pink',marginTop:14}}>
              Click on me!{"\n"}
              onPress:{this.state.count_onPress}{"\n"}
              onPressIn:{this.state.count_onPressIn}{"\n"}
              onPressOut:{this.state.count_onPressOut}{"\n"}
              onLongPress:{this.state.count_onLongPress}{"\n"}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AppRegistry.registerComponent('react_native_app1', () => TouchableOpacityTest);
```

You may replace the `<ScrollView>` with a `<View>` component on the above code and you will see that **onPress** event fires every time, even when the focus is on the `<TextView>`

***NOTE:*** I am working on Android. I have no idea if this happens also on iOS.

***NOTE 2:*** According to Aakash Sigdel, this is indeed happening on iOS too.

Comment: try using one of keyboardDismissMode={'none', 'ondrag','interactive'}

Comment: I checked it on iOS and can confirm that this happens in iOS too.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a <TouchableOpacity> next to a ScrollView, but the problem was not fixed when removing the ScrollView. Instead, I increased the size of my button to the minimum recommended size of 44x44. After that, the button recognized all tap events.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TouchableOpacity as Item in ListView only reacts after TextInput has lost focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290787/touchableopacity-as-item-in-listview-only-reacts-after-textinput-has-lost-focus)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` on your `ScrollView`.

Duplicate answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290788/29493

**UPDATE:** As Hossein writes in his answer, `true|false` has been deprecated in newer versions in favor of `always|never|handled`.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy :)

Answer (score 11):

Set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` to your `ScrollView` props.

**React Native Documentation:**

**'never'** (the default), tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children won't receive the tap.

**'always'**, the keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and the scroll view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view can catch taps.

**'handled'**, the keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by a children, (or captured by an ancestor).

**false**, deprecated, use 'never' instead.

**true**, deprecated, use 'always' instead.

Comment: If helps anyone, same problem happened to me only on `iPhone X` did not happen on `iPhone 6 plus`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using *alignItems:'baseline',* when I switched to *alignItems:'center'*, it started working smoothly. Don't know why