# pressing twice to make the button work when TextInput is focused

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem when trying to submit data from the `TextInput` component. When trying to press the button that invoke the callback that handle the text, there is a need to press it twice for it to work. Once for the `TextInput` lose its focus and the second time to invoke the callback. 
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290787/touchableopacity-as-item-in-listview-only-reacts-after-textinput-has-lost-focus) solution but it didnt worked for me.

COMPONENT:

```
  <Modal>
    <ScrollView>
      <Card>
        <CardImage source={{uri: this.props.linkImage}}/>
        <CardContent/>
      </Card>
      {
        this.state.single.map((comment) => {
          return comment[3] ?  
            <Comp/> : null                                           
          })
      }
  </ScrollView> 
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>   
      <CardAction>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <IconFA name="reply"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <IconEn name="thumbs-up"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <IconEn name="thumbs-down"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </CardAction> 
      <CardAction>
        <TextInput ref={input => this.input = input}/>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <IconFA name="rocket"/>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      </CardAction> 
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>             
  </Modal>
```

Comment: which value did you provide to keyboardShouldPersistTaps prop?

Comment: `always` although I might miss-placed it, which component should I wrap inside  `keyboardShouldPersistTaps `?

Comment: `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">`

Comment: yeah but which component you suggest to wrap with it?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" prop to ScrollView wrapping your component like this:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
   ...content
<ScrollView>
```